# Name error in Python in 'self' definition

Tags: python, linux

Getting `Name Error:` in python code as shared below. I am a beginner in Python.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import I2CGenericFrame
import os

class I2CApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, I2CGenericFrame.Ui_winI2CMain):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


    self.cmbBusListBox.addItem("Slect ..")
```

It is giving following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I2cMain.py", line 6, in <module>
    class I2CApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, I2CGenericFrame.Ui_winI2CMain):
  File "I2cMain.py", line 12, in I2CApp
    self.cmbBusListBox.addItem("Slect ..")
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Guide me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your indentation is off for that line throwing the error.

Comment: Your last line is *outside* of any method. It is executed when the class definition is run (so when your module is imported). Since it is outside of a method, there is no `self` local variable.

Comment: `self.cmbBusListBox.addItem` is defined outside `__init__` - and outside `__init__` name `self` does not exist.

Comment: Also, do **not** use `super(self.__class__, self)`. Ever. That'll lead to infinite recursion errors when you subclass this. See [How to avoid infinite recursion with super()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4235078)

Answer (score 1):

`self` is an argument like any other that is passed in a method. It has no meaning in the class body outside of a method.

You can resolve this by fixing the indentation so that it is referenced inside the `__init__` method:

```
class I2CApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, I2CGenericFrame.Ui_winI2CMain):
    def __init__(self):
        super(I2CApp, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.cmbBusListBox.addItem("Slect ..")
```

EDIT: As indicated in the comment, you should also call `super` with the class explicitly, to avoid the possibility of infinite recursion.

Comment: Please, please, *please* correct the `super()` call too. See [How to avoid infinite recursion with super()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4235078)

Answer (score 0):

the variable `self` is passed to methods automatically when you call them from an object.  Your line of code `self.cmbBusListBox.addItem("Slect ..")` is not contained within a method of the Class and therefore it does not know what `self` is.  This is probably an indentation error.  Did you intend for it to be under `__init__`?